# Get All Users in django

Tags: django, django-views

I want to display all the users, in my template but I i received this error.
TypeError at /list/
**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

**views.py**

```
class UsersView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'list.html'
 context = super(UsersView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
 context['object_list'] = User.objects.values()
```

**list.html**

```
           <tbody>            
           <tr>
              
           <th scope="col">Id</th>
           <th scope="col">username</th>
            <th scope="col">email Adress</th>
            <th scope="col">First Name </th>
            <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                
               </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                {% for user in users %}
                <tr> 
            <td>{{ user.id }} </td>
            <td>{{ user.username}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
```

How could you pull all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `self` nor `context`, etc. in a class. You should override the [**`.get_context_data(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin.get_context_data):

```
class UsersView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'list.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(UsersView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['object_list'] = User.objects.all()
        return context
```

You named your template variable `ojbect_list`, so you should iterate over `object_list`, not `users`:

```
{% for user in object_list %}
    <tr> 
        <td>{{ user.id }} </td>
        <td>{{ user.username}}</td>
        <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{ user.last_name }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

It might however make more sense to use a [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) instead:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class UsersView(ListView):
    template_name = 'list.html'
    model = User
```